# Mock is giving missing method exception in spock framewrok

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

I am running my Junit test cases for my groovy class using spock framework I am using `Mock` to invoke my class. but it is giving me `MissingMethodException` but if I invoke the same method by normal creating object `def obj = new MyClass()` way it is working. please let me know am I missing something? below is my stacktrace

```
Expected no exception to be thrown, but got 'groovy.lang.MissingMethodException'
    at spock.lang.Specification.noExceptionThrown(Specification.java:119)
    at .AsplTest.fetchXmlTest(AsplTest.groovy:35)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.webservice.Service.fetchAsplXml() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, groovy.net.xmlrpc.XMLRPCServerProxy, java.lang.String) values: [3c98fa0dd1b5d92af599779bfb7be655, groovy.net.xmlrpc.XMLRPCServerProxy@797b0699, ...]
Possible solutions: getFetchAsplXml()
    at .AsplTest.fetchXmlTest(AsplTest.groovy:33)
```

below is my test code

```
public void fetchXmlTest() {
        given:
        def asplObject=Mock(Service);
        when:
        asplObject.fetchXml(sessionId, serverProxy, "https://serverproxy")
        then:
        noExceptionThrown()
    }
```

FYI:
my groovy version is 2.4.12 and spock version 1.1-groovy-2.4

Comment: You're mocking to a variable called `object`, then calling `asplObject.fetchXml`?  Try `object.fetchXml`

Comment: oohh sorry it was my typo. code updated properly. updated the code

Comment: Please provide the whole code. Apparently  from your error message , we need to know what  `com.webservice.Service.fetchAsplXml` and  sessionId, serverProxy are.

Comment: I reckon `Service` doesn't have that method with those parameters

Comment: @tim_yates it was there because when I invoked normal class object it was working

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you are doing things backwards.

Mocks are not test subjects. They are used to control the interactions of your test subjects with other objects. It looks, from the code you posted, that you want to test the invocation of method fetchXml on your Service object.

To do this, you need to create an instance of Service, and call the method. If your Service has collaborating objects, then you can Mock them, and add interactions, like this:

```
given:
def service = new Service()

and:
service.collaboratingObject = Mock(CollaboratingObjectClass)


when:
service.getFetchAsplXml()

then:
1 * service.collaboratingObject.someMethodReturningAString(_ as String) >> {String input-> "mockedResult from $input" as String }
```

Comment: Hi can you please let me know what does kean by collaborating in spock context? Why I wanted to mock is my method downloads big size files from server so on my unit test I want to avoid that

Comment: does your service do all the work, or does it have references to other services that do part of its work?

Comment: there are some depedency on other method also

Comment: if the service does not have variables that hold references to other services or injected spring beans, then there is nothing to mock. I thin kyou have a very superficial understanding, not only of spock, but also of grails and spring. It's hard to help you.

Comment: ya may be..:( but I can tell there are spring bean injections using context loader

Comment: i don't understand what you mean by your last comment.